# how to solve run time error of [__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iphone, in my code getting run time error of  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e6e300'

my code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Animalfile" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *animal=[dict valueForKey:@"image"];
    NSLog(@"print:%@",dict);
    NSLog(@"hello:%@",animal);

    UIImage *img=[animal objectAtIndex:currentImage];
        [animalphoto setImage:img];

}
```

give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my code....

Answer (score 11):

The problem happens when you attempt treating a string as an image:

```
UIImage *img = [animal objectAtIndex:currentImage];
```

The value inside the `animal` array cannot be an image, because the array comes from a dictionary `dict` that you read from a file using the `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` method. [This method will create objects of types `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). `UIImage` is not on the list of types that can be created by the `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` method, so your cast is invalid.

From the error message it appears that you are getting an `NSString` instead of `UIImage`. Check the value of that string to see what it represents: it is probably a URL, a file name, or some other form of identifier that can be used to obtain an image. Depending on what's in the string, change your program to load `img` rather based on the value of the string. Perhaps the code should be

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[animal objectAtIndex:currentImage]];
```

but it is impossible to tell for sure without knowing the value of your string.

Comment: `UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[animal objectAtIndex:currentImage]];`